# How can I changue URL in redmine code (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have a Redmine installation mounted in a virtual machine. I can access it by using my IP in the browser.
But when I want to enter from an external link (since I have my virtual machine on a server), I have this external link

```
http://companyname.com/MyServer/myVirtualMachineName/
```

And I can access my Redmine, but the CSS doesn't load and all links are incorrectly routed, for example:

```
http://companyname.com/login
```

I need to change it into:

```
http://companyname.com/MyServer/myVirtualMachineName/login
```

How can I change it?

- I work with Apache.
- Rails 3.2.22 (I can't update it)
- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux] (same issue as with Ruby: I can't update it)

Comment: See https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI for the necessary configuration changes.

Comment: I still have the same problem, i don't know where the url is called